# How to pass EF6 Entity to new page on different server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web app (using webForms not mvc) that takes user input and adds it to a database table. This app will be available to users in a dev, qa, and production environment hitting each environments own database.

Currently, I have a promote button that works by connecting to the QA database from Dev or the Prod database from QA inserting/updating the data there and then redirecting to the QA/Prod version of the app.

Instead of doing it this way I would like to save myEntity in a variable and send it with the redirect. I'm thinking something like this:

```
MyEntityType myEntity = UserInputData();
Response.Redirect("myQAurl", myEntity);
```

Then in my QA Page_Load have something like:

```
If( fromDev ){
    loadPageWithMyEntity();
}
```

By doing it this way I hope to prevent QA/Prod database connections directly from dev --> QA or QA --> Prod.

If passing an Entity wont work I could also use an array, list, etc.

Comment: Any data in a redirect would need to be in the query string.  Can you represent your entity on the query string as a set of key/value pairs?  Or perhaps a JSON-serialized version of the entity to then be de-serialized by the receiving page?

Comment: There are 40+ fields in my entity (I know its a lot but I am not the DB admin) so putting them in the query string is not ideal. Also, the data includes a password. Perhaps I can use the json serialization, Would I need to make a connection to the server to pass the json object or is there a way to use the destination url?

Comment: If you serialize the object then that string would be the value in a query string key/value pair.  It would have to be URL-encoded, of course.  And the endpoint receiving it will need to de-serialize it from a string to the entity.  Note that this could make a *very* long URL for a large entity, which could be problematic.  If the entity is that large, then you may need to put it in form fields on the page and use JavaScript to make a POST request from the browser, as a redirect wouldn't work for a POST.  As for passwords... Why are those being sent in this manner in the first place?

Comment: It isn't being sent this way yet, and may not be if it isn't a good idea. This is all done in an intranet and while the passwords are 'passwords' they don't really protect high value content. They are just to allow a trading partner access to a directory that is specific to them to drop off an edi document.

Comment: User passwords shouldn't be stored in any retrievable manner in the first place.  You should never be able to read them, and at no point should the system ever *output* them (even in hashed form).  It doesn't matter if the content being protected is of low value.  People have a strong tendency to re-use passwords.  Chances are that you're currently storing someone's banking password, and you shouldn't be able to read it.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps I will just keep my app the way it is. Although, we do create the passwords ourselves for each setup so I seriously doubt they are being used for other things. But, you are still right.

Comment: Even though I am not going to use your suggestion it does answer my question if you want to put it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing a redirect:

```
Response.Redirect("myQAurl", myEntity);
```

The way that works is that the server basically tells the browser to make a GET request to the supplied URL.  Which means that any information sent over that redirect has to be in the query string on that URL.  So you would have two options:

1. Include a bunch of key/value pairs in the query string which can be used to re-construct the entity on the other end.
2. Serialize the entity to a string and have one key/value pair with that as the value, then de-serialize to the entity on the other end.

If the entity is large, this could be problematic.  There's a reasonable limit to the size of a URL in most web servers.

For large entities, to truly transfer from one system to another where they don't share any back end you would likely need a POST request.  Which can't be done with a redirect.  Instead, you would show the user a form (which could be entirely hidden and invisible, so not necessarily *shown*) and the user would have to post that form (which could be done with JavaScript, so not necessarily the *user* posting it).

Beyond those, you're likely looking at a back-end hand-off, such as storing the data in a temporary database location on one system and consuming it on the other.